# Zend Framework 2 Error ListenerOptions not found

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I need help setting up Zend Framework 2. I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Module\Listener\ListenerOptions' not found in index.php

Why is the class not found?

This is my index.php:

```
<?php
chdir(dirname(__DIR__));
require_once './vendor/ZendFramework/library' . '/Zend/Loader/AutoloaderFactory.php';
Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory::factory();

$appConfig = include './config/application.config.php';

$listenerOptions = new Zend\Module\Listener\ListenerOptions($appConfig['module_listener_options']);
$defaultListeners = new Zend\Module\Listener\DefaultListenerAggregate($listenerOptions);
$defaultListeners->getConfigListener()->addConfigGlobPath("config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.config.php");


$moduleManager = new Zend\Module\Manager($appConfig['modules']);
$moduleManager->events()->attachAggregate($defaultListeners);
$moduleManager->loadModules();

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$bootstrap = new Zend\Mvc\Bootstrap($defaultListeners->getConfigListener()->getMergedConfig());
$application = new Zend\Mvc\Application;
$bootstrap->bootstrap($application);
$application->run()->send();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Zend\Module\Listener\ListenerOptions` is now under `Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\ListenerOptions` check this class and other related to the Namespace `Zend\Module\Listener`